# Simple Tkinter program with "Abort trap: 6" error

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, homebrew

I've installed Tkinter on OSX using `brew`, more specifically:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk
```

and subsequently,

```
brew install python --with-tcl-tk
```

but when I execute a simple code such as:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
```

Python crashes and the terminal displays "Abort trap: 6".
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Ask the homebrew folks, or try the PSF installer (and replace Apple's tcl/tk as directed) or try MacPorts (sp.?).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an ongoing issue (see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/12114) and poernahi's solution worked for me.

I mean: brewing python without `--with-tcl-tk`.